# Sessions with local storage

Tags: php, javascript, html, local-storage, session-cookies

I am very new to javascript and localstorage usage for HTML5. I am currently using PHP sessions in my site and want to move over to localstorage as I am using cookies at this time to renew the sessions.

I understand that localstorage is a client-side function and not server-side like PHP so this makes it hard for me to figure out how to approach this.

All I want to do is set the localstorage values (which I have done already) but I need to be able to pass them back into PHP to re-establish them as SESSION variables (I have to do this as my site has over 100 pages and upwards of 50 session variables at one time so I would like to simply use the localstorage to regenerate the session variables instead of cookies.

If anyone can help me out with this it would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you want this?  Local storage can be altered by the client easily. Don't rely on what the client tells you to set your sessions.  Use a database instead.

Comment: I agree with @Truth - I fail to see the purpose of this or what you might think you would gain by doing this other than enabling the client to tamper with the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your going to need to use ajax, or some form of way to contact your server to allow this. The only way you can access that local storage is using a client side script(javascript), which in turn can do things with it. I don't know ajax, but you should look into that. I also agree with @Truth, local storage is nice, especially if you don't want to use cookies, but the only benefit is the user can use that local storage offline. So theres really no real reason you should do that. If you use cookies, you can access that info through your script. You could on the other hand use local storage as an alternative to cookies being disabled on the users browser.

Comment: I am having users complain that the "add to homescreen" webapp doesn't keep them logged in for the set time in our PHP.ini and cookie limits. Through the website it does work, but my client insists the webapp follow these limits as well so from hours of googling I found many in my position opted to use localstorage... @truth - You say use a database? I am using a mysql to check the credentials of the user upon login, how could I use the database to keep a session alive? and would it work in the webapp scenario? you have me quite interested in this possible solution. Do share please. :)

Comment: I am honestly not sure why the cookie is not setting correctly, but from what I am aware, you should always set that yourself. As for how to keep the session with a cookie and a database, create a well hashed random string that you put in your database and cookie when a user wants to say logged in. If they match, you are good to go. With local storage, its the same thing, except again, you need to communicate with the server using Ajax or another form of script that can communicate with your server to see if a user has that random hashed string. Be aware of possible cookie/localstorage theft.

Comment: I am setting the cookies, it all works the way it should in the browser. As soon as you "add to home screen" and load through that way it ignores the cookies. From what I read on other forums and on here is that this is common and localstorage is the workaround. Would the random hash be the PHP SESSION ID?

Comment: Nope. Random, maybe date time combined with other useless information. What I do is make a random string generator, then hash it. In reality, you don't even need to hash as long as its random. But the hash makes it even more random, so doesn't hurt. As long as it isn't sensitive data, its up to you. But be aware that you should also store the user IP to make sure that the string being stored isn't stolen and hence giving someone else access to that users profile. Not a big deal if you don't hold sensitive data, but good practice.

Comment: Thanks! I've started working on this, I just don't know how I would call it as the webApp seems to ignore the cookies and they're used to regenerate the session. I'll give my client an etch n sketch and tell them the session on that thing doesn't expire unless you shake it! :P